# How to load locally stored images conditionally in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="item">
      <h1>Price: {{ item.email }}</h1>
      <v-if item.email=="john@gmail.com">
        <img :src="../"/>
      </v-if>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { routerid } from "./routerid";
export default {
  name: "User",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      item: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadData();
  },
  computed: {
    routeId() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },
  },

  watch: {
    routeId() {
      console.log("Reload (route change)");
      this.loadData();
    },
  },

  methods: {
    loadData() {
      console.log("Reloading, ID", this.routeId);
      if (!this.routeId) return;
      routerid(this.$route.params.id).then((item) => {
        this.item = item.data;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How to load  locally stored images conditionally in Vuejs?

I have three images stored inside of my assets folder.  as below.

[image]

Now in frontend i want to call them conditionally like for example **(if ---> john@gmail.com show the john image stored inside of assets folder.** Else no. Similarly for other images too. Like derk and Kate...

Do i need to write if else condition. To load the images based on email? Or any other way to do that?

Code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/combined-logic-api-forked-nzzzwc?file=/src/components/User.vue

api response:- **https://fakestoreapi.com/users/1**

**{"address":{"geolocation":{"lat":"-37.3159","long":"81.1496"},"city":"kilcoole","street":"new road","number":7682,"zipcode":"12926-3874"},"id":1,"email":"john@gmail.com","username":"johnd","password":"m38rmF$","name":{"firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"},"phone":"1-570-236-7033","__v":0}**

Note:- email will be different for each id.

Answer (score 0):

First. I think you should provide image link on your API Response (so you should add image link column on your database table). Or if you insist, based on your case, you can use this:

```
<div v-if="item">
  <h1>Price: {{ item.email }}</h1>
  <img :src="getPic(item.email)"/>
</div>
```

and in your method:

```
getPic(src) {
  return "@/assets/" + src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf("@")) + ".png"
}
```

But I still really think you should store iamge link in your database

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/combined-logic-api-forked-nzzzwc?file=/src/components/User.vue

Corrected code, as per your changes.  not getting where are we pointing to image...   Can I please know .. out of all the images stored inside of assets folder. I want to pick only one. For example.. if john show john image only...

Comment: And also getting errors like :- Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')"
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')